# How to remove offset of axis in matplotlib 3d plot?

Tags: matplotlib

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([0, 1])

plt.show()
```

results in the following plot:
[image: matplotlib 3d box]

There is a small margin between the axis and there limits.
How can I get rid of this **offset of the axis**.
For example `ax.set_xlim([0, 1])` has not effect!